# Ramda path for array values

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I have the Ramda code below which won't work.
Is it because of `appSessions[0]`? and if yes, how should I write? Also how do I add a default if that value isn't found?

```
R.path(['appSessions[0]', 'personalInfo', 'personalInfo'], response);
```

Comment: You're looking for [`pathOr`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#pathOr)

Comment: but what about appSessions[0] ? is that correct ?

Comment: how your response object looks like ?

Comment: Not it isn't. It's a path of its own

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't want `['appSession[0]', ...]` but `['appSession', 0, ...]`:

The nodes supplied to `path` can be either strings (for objects) or numbers (for arrays):

```js
const response = {
  appSessions: [
    {
      id: 1,
      personalInfo: { personalInfo: {foo: 'bar'}, other: true },
      another: 1
    }, {
      id: 2,
      personalInfo: { personalInfo: {foo: 'qux'}, other: 99 },
      another: false
    }
  ]
}

console .log (
  R .path (['appSessions', 0, 'personalInfo', 'personalInfo'], response)
)
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

That actual path looks strange to me, with `personalInfo` nested inside `personalInfo`, but it will work.